# Error code 7B73D32B when trying to update staged rollout to 100.0 on new Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

[image: staged rollout]

I am receiving this error: `An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (7B73D32B)` when trying to update my rollout to 100(.0) as int or float on a staged rollout release that is currently in my production track. I can rollout to 99.99999% fine, it's just when I try to update it to 100.0 (or 100) where I am receiving this error. Please note that I am retaining no APKs in this release, or dropping support or anything wonky.

This is my first time releasing a staged rollout to 100% on the new gplay console, so I might be missing something. Googling this error yields approximately zero results, and I see no recourse for where to seek further clarity on this issue. Any assistance in this matter would be helpful, thank you.

Expected behavior:

- I go into Google Play Console. I update my staged rollout to 100.0. My app is now served to 100% of my player base.

Actual behavior:

- I go into the new Google Play Console. I update my staged rollout to 100.0. I cannot do this because it errors out due to mysterious undocumented circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was just an internal server error from Google; for anyone encountering this in the future, I just had to wait ~2 days and I was able to update the rollout to 100%. Would have been nice to have some reasonable error messaging so I wasn't searching the entire console & associated documentation for a button I might have missed on their new redesign, but it is how it is I suppose.